# HIVE UNION ALL with clause

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have the below mysql update statement. I am trying to convert this into hql using hive 13.(so i do not have any update statement in hive)

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE.STORE SET
  ADDRESS1 = b.addr_line_1
  ,ADDRESS3 = b.city + ', ' + b.state + ' ' + b.postal_cde
FROM
  MY_TABLE.STORE a INNER JOIN
  CUST b ON
    a.REGION = b.LOC_NUM
  AND a.STORENUMBER = b.cust_num;


UPDATE MY_TABLE.STORE SET
  STORETYPE = b.abc_num
FROM
  MY_TABLE.STORE a INNER JOIN
  RLT b ON
    a.REGION = b.LOC_NUM
  AND a.STORENUMBER = b.CUST_NUM;
```

Below is my query:

```
insert into table X
select b.addr_line_1,CONCAT(B.CITY, ', ', B.STATE, ' ', B.POSTAL_CDE),STORETYPE
from  MY_TABLE.STORE A JOIN CUST b ON a.REGION = b.LOC_NUM
  AND a.STORENUMBER = b.cust_num t1

UNION ALL
select ADDRESS1 ,ADDRESS3 ,b.abc_num from  MY_TABLE.STORE a INNER JOIN
  RLT b ON
    a.REGION = b.LOC_NUM
  AND a.STORENUMBER = b.CUST_NUM t2 on t1.id <> t2.id;
```

The above query throws an error for parsing.
I know there should be 2 queries , 1 if Primary keys are equal and other if they are not equal.

Above query is for equal PK condition.
where Id is the PK. Any help please. Have been quite long researching on this.

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE in Hive before version .14  is INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE OR PARTITION.
You need LEFT JOIN to select all rows from STORE including updated and not updated. 
Check into CASE statement which table is joined.
Use folowing query as a template:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE STORE
SELECT
-- fields should be in the same order like in target table (STORE)
--update all joined records, leave as is if not joined: 

case when c.LOC_NUM is not null then c.addr_line_1 --first table joined
     when r.LOC_NUM is not null then r.addr_line_1 --second table joined
     else s.address1                               --not joined
 end                                                                   as address1, 

    ... 

FROM STORE s
     LEFT JOIN CUST c ON s.REGION = c.LOC_NUM
                     AND s.STORENUMBER = c.cust_num 
     LEFT JOIN  RLT r ON s.REGION = r.LOC_NUM
                     AND s.STORENUMBER = r.CUST_NUM ;
```

Implement your equal/not equal logic also in the CASEs.

Also you need to double check that joins do not create duplicates.